# How to put an outcome of a function in Kotlin into a Textview

Tags: android, function, kotlin, text, textview

I am quite new with programming in Kotlin in Android Studio.
I created a function and now I want to put the outcome of the function into a textview.
I am struggling with this for a couple of days now and I cant figure out how to do this. I used a function I found here on Stackoverflow of a welcome message based on time. It is the following function:

```
fun getGreetingMessage(): String {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)       
    return when (timeOfDay) {
        in 0..11 -> "Good morning"
        in 12..15 -> "Goede afternoon"
        in 16..20 -> "Goede evening"
        else -> "Hello"
```

The outcome of this function must be presented in a Textview on my main page can someone please help me out here?

many thanks,

Rick

Comment: Use: `myTextVeiw.text = getGreetingMessage()`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question you asked the problem is assigning data to TextView.

now let`s say the `id` of TextView is `some_id`

the code should look something like this.

```
//getting data from getGreetingMessageFunction
val greetingMessage = getGreetingMessage()
//declaring the view
val requiredView =  view.findViewId<TextView>(R.id.some_id)
//assigning the greeting message to the required view
requiredView.text=greetingMessage
    
    fun getGreetingMessage(): String {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        return when (timeOfDay) {
            in 0..11 -> "Good morning"
            in 12..15 -> "Goede afternoon"
            in 16..20 -> "Goede evening"
            else -> "Hello"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Tnx for the reply.
Tried this in a couple of ways but somehow it doesnt work.
When I try it in the way explained above, the getGreetingMessage isn't created yet so it doesnt recognize the function. Do you know a way to fix this?

Tnx

Comment: @Ricka can you post the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: It says 'Unresolved reference:getGreetingmessage' when I put the line "val greetingMessage = getGreetingMessage()" above the function.

Comment: I don't feel there is a mistake in the function, the question needs more clarity.

Comment: I tried the function code and got the answer in logcat ```2021-09-18 02:21:54.431 /com.exxxx.xxxx D/MainActivity: Goede afternoon
 ```

Comment: Looks like my function doesnt start at all in Logcat

Comment: post more details about your code, like where are you calling it from how are you declaring the textView. More details about the error you are receiving.

Comment: Yes! Got it!, many thanks! The problem was that I didnt close the function"getGreetingmessage" properly so I couldnt code outside the body, code was unreachable. Calling the function didnt work out.